# Problem with datetime module-Python

Tags: python

How come this works:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = '%d' % now.month

print month
```

But this doesn't?

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = '%m' % now.month

print month
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%m is not a supported format character for the % operator. Here is the list of supported [formating characters](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for this operator

%m is valid when your are using [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) function to build a date string

Comment: @Seamus Longinal: Those directives are specifically to the 'format' argument of time.strftime(format[, t])
http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 1):

`'%d'` is a format character that insert a "signed integer decimal", `'%m'` has no such meaning. The possible format characters are listed [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).